# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' What proces is causing this?

Tags: mysql, debian

I got this connections constantly in logs, how to trace what app is trying to connect?

root@localhost is allowed to connect

`190310 22:38:57 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
190310 22:38:59 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
190310 22:38:59 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
190310 22:39:03 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do this unfortunately since your SSH daemon is logging. Here is how I would tackle this:

1. Perform multiple netstats / lsof commands to determine what exactly is generating a network connection on port 22
2. Shut down any public facing services and see if the log stops writing.
3. Perform multiple process output snapshots to check if any suspect programs (python/perl/php) are constantly generated.
4. Check cron entries for all users.

Comment: This belongs in dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that these 'users' are *different*:

```
root@localhost
root@'11.22.33.44'  -- or any IP or host
```

You *may* have initially established `GRANTs` for `root@localhost`, but not for going across TCP/IP (or vice versa).  Or you gave them different passwords.

Comment: I'm aware of that, the question is about tracing process wich is trying to login on localhost.